# Global fields for classes

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, derived-class

A pretty common issue I come across, is where I have some fields and I want to reference them through a class which is <del>derived</del> initialized from the class of the fields.
Let me be more specific.

[image: Class Diagram]

<del>I have those three classes that derives from a main class.</del> 
Each class has a method that interacts with a field. In this case a have a JFrame that invoke a class (a JPanel) and add it to the content pane.

The way I found is by passing a reference of the object that the Frame class creates to the constructor of the Panel class. And reference them through that.

Is there a more efficient way? How can I create global fields,or methods <del>for all the derived classes?</del>In this case they are components of the main class?

**UPDATE**

Something like this.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JFrame1 extends JFrame {

    protected String field1;
    protected String field2;

    public JFrame1() {
        add(new Panel1());
    } 
}

class Panel1 extends JPanel {

    public Panel1() {

         //   field1 = "String"; Wrong
        }
    }
```

I know I can nest `class Panel1` inside `public class Frame1` and the problem will be solved,but what if **I want the two classes in different files**?

Comment: what do you mean by _derived_ ?

Comment: @Qwe I meant that are created/initialized/invoked I don't know the exact word I have to use.

Comment: easies would be to wrote that as answering your qeustion, please edit yout question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), otherwise there are some web pages where you can sent order based on picture against payments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I thing I found a way.

The Frame class

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JFrame1 extends JFrame {

    private String field1;

    public JFrame1() {
        add(new PanelA());
    } 

class PanelA extends Panel1 {

  @Override
  public String getField1() {
       return field1
  }
}
```

Create an interface

```
public interface Connector {
    public String getField1();
}
```

And the Panel1 class

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public abstract class Panel1 extends JPanel implements Connector {

    field1 = getField1();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*three classes that derives from a main class* - what does this mean? Your three classes derive from (extend) a JPanel, and it doesn't have any fields in it.

If you're asking how your three classes should access the fields from `Frame1` which presumably is their container - then you should use [`getParent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getParent%28%29) to get reference to the parent class, check if it is `Frame1` and if yes - access its fields.

Comment: You are write `how my three classes access the fields from Frame1`. I use `getParent()` but I can't cast JPanel to Frame1 class.

Comment: agreed with your shot to the dark +1